# Vertica - Refresh view definition for adding newly added columns in the underlying table

Tags: database, vertica

I have a requirement that need to refresh view definition to have the latest columns from its underlying table. Do we have such a command can achieve it? Because the underlying table of a view may be changing, and I don't really want to query sys view table to see now which table is the underlying table of a view, I just want to have ALL the latest columns to appear in the view.

For example, we have two tables, like `test_1` and `test_2`, and also a view called `test` which on day 1 the underlying query of the view is `select * from test_1`, and on day 2 it's `select * from test_2`, but the table schema may be changed within a day, I want the view test always have all the columns of its underlying table.

One approach to achieve it is to query `VIEWS` and get the definition of the view and know the underlying table, and drop and re-create it with `select * from $underlying_table`, that we can have all the columns.

But you know query sys table sometimes is very slow, is there a elegant way like "refresh view" to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

No solution here ! this is on the suggestion list with HP Vertica.

In views that require

```
select * from table
```

i rebuild/recreate(i don't even look at the system tables - they are slow because they are external tables )  them every time i make changes in prod, it sucks doing this but it is what it is.

Comment: Thank Up_One. I got no solution for this either as searching for several days :(